# Django 1.10 & Django-cms 3.4.4 - NoReverseMatch for some browsers

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I stumbled across on a very strange issue. The dev env is Django 1.10 & django-cms 3.4.4. When I try to load localhost in Chrome & Firefox everything works fine, but if I try to open it in Safari, it fails with **NoReverseMatch at /** and it fails with random urls. I also tried to

```
curl http://localhost:8000/
```

and it works fine. 
Also tried on Windows and different browsers and it fails for some browsers with the same error.
Does someone have any idea what could be the issue?
Thanks!

P.S.

```
Reverse for 'model' with arguments '(u'bmw',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

It seems that it doesn't load any urls at all. **0 patterns tried** means there is nothing loaded I guess?

Comment: What does `curl -I http://localhost:8000/` return?

Comment: `HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 08 Aug 2017 19:32:39 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.13
Content-Language: bg
Expires: Tue, 08 Aug 2017 19:33:39 GMT
Vary: , Accept-Language, Cookie
Last-Modified: Tue, 08 Aug 2017 19:32:39 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=60
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie:  csrftoken=cjyVDImNRxEsijnKlMHrzAHgXSObdhxfWzTY5VTehmAWS6HRU5P99RJ2Wq0i98bj; expires=Tue, 07-Aug-2018 19:32:39 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie:  django_language=bg; expires=Wed, 08-Aug-2018 19:32:39 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/`

Answer (score 2):

I think I found it. Long story short

The default cms is configured to use English as primary language, but I want my primary language to be Bulgarian. I configured the CMS to support both languages and I've made Bulgarian to be default and English is disabled. Then I got rid of the `i18n_patterns()` wrapper in `urls.py` to get rid of the `/en/` `/bg/` etc prefixes. So far so good. The admin site works great. There is only one language - Bulgarian, there are pages and custom apps attached to them. When I load the front end with wrong url on Safari just to see all the supported URLs, I can't see any applications attached and urls for them. If I do the same with Chrome - it shows urls for all attached applications. It turns out that Chrome loads the Bulgarian page configuration and all the configured applications, but Safari loads the English page which is disabled and there are no attached applications to it.

My first guess was the Accept-Language header. Safari uses `Accept-Language: en`, but other browsers send bg. I tried to tamper the data, but nothing happened. Then I noticed there is a `django_language` cookie being used by the `LocaleMiddleware` that actually determines the language. When I disabled the middleware, everything worked like a charm.

Thanks!